# Creating a transaction in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a function as `$scope.submit()` in my `angular js` application. Following is the code.

```
scope.submit = function () {
    var reqDate = dateFilter(scope.first.date, scope.df);
    this.formData.locale = scope.optlang.code;
    this.formData.active = this.formData.active || false;
    this.formData.dateFormat = scope.df;
    this.formData.activationDate = reqDate;

    if (routeParams.groupId) {
        this.formData.groupId = routeParams.groupId;
    }

    if (routeParams.officeId) {
        this.formData.officeId = routeParams.officeId;
    }

    if (scope.first.submitondate) {
        reqDate = dateFilter(scope.first.submitondate, scope.df);
        this.formData.submittedOnDate = reqDate;
    }

    if (scope.first.dateOfBirth) {
        this.formData.dateOfBirth = dateFilter(scope.first.dateOfBirth, scope.df);
    }

    if (!scope.opensavingsproduct) {
        this.formData.savingsProductId = null;
    }
    resourceFactory.clientResource.save(this.formData, function (data) {
        scope.newid = data.clientId;
        return  scope.newid
    });
    resourceFactory.clientIdenfierResource.save({
        clientId: scope.newid
    }, this.formData2, function (data) {
        location.path('/viewclient/' + data.clientId);
    });
};
```

The first `resourceFactory.clientResource.save` creates a client and pass the client id. The second `resourceFactory.clientIdenfierResource.save` creates the identifier like passport number and check if another client with the same passport number exists.

i wanted to roll back first one if the second doesn't finish. Like if we have a transaction,

- save 1 = first transaction
- save 2 = second transaction

if save 2 has finished then commit rest of the transaction. How can i do it in `angular`. Please advise.

Comment: You cannot do transaction over HTTP, what you need to do is to move the  business to backend and do transaction based on SQL.

Comment: thank you now it's clear